# How did the LEGO 7862 Remote Controlled Decoupling and Signal work?

Tags: trains, remote-control, 12v

I've never seen this set in person, although it appears occasionally in 12V Lego train system images. I've never seen it used, or described.

How did the *LEGO 7862 Remote Controlled Decoupling and Signal 12V* work? What is the 'Signal' component of the decoupler?

[image: Box image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It basically forces the coupling magnets to separate via the pins pointing downwards from the magnet holders:

[image]

[image]

Here's a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnND5HTf9uw).

Comment: That's a cool video!